# Pandas dataframe - sort and shift within a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like below

[image]

This dataframe is already grouped by the three columns `O`, `A`, `N` but as you see it is NOT sorted by `time` column

My goal is to sort it based on the `time` column by maintaining the groupby of `O`, `A`, `N` and then do `shift(-1)` operation for `value` column to create a `value_next` observation.

The output should look like below (`NaN` is imputed with `-`1` for demonstration)

[image]

I did below:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# Initialize data to lists.
data = [{'time': 10, 'O': 1, 'A': 2, 'N':3, 'value': 10},
        {'time': 7, 'O': 1, 'A': 2, 'N':3, 'value': 11},
       {'time': 15, 'O': 1, 'A': 2, 'N':3, 'value': 12},
       {'time': 11, 'O': 2, 'A': 2, 'N':3, 'value': 20},
        {'time': 12, 'O': 2, 'A': 2, 'N':3, 'value': 21},
       {'time': 1, 'O': 2, 'A': 2, 'N':3, 'value': 25}]
  
# Creates DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
#sorting
df.sort_values(by=['O', 'A', 'N', 'time'], ascending=[True, True, True, True])

#shift
df['value_next'] = df.groupby(['O', 'A', 'N'])['value'].shift(-1)
```

This generates output below which is different than the expected. What am I missing?

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_values` is not an inplace operation by default. Either pass `inplace=True`

```
df.sort_values(['O','A', 'N', 'time'], inplace=True)
# other operations
```

or reassign:

```
df = df.sort_values(...)
# other operations
```